# Symfony2: Is it possible to place validation annotations on an interface?

Tags: symfony

Say I have the interface:

```
namespace Acme\Bundle\FooBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

interface IFoo {

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\MaxLength(3000)
     */
    function getBody();

}
```

Two classes implement the interface and I want those classes to also be able to make use of the validation annotations on the `getBody` declaration. (i.e. I don't want to have to duplicate the validation code in each subclass implementing `IFoo` since it violates DRY).

Doing this however gives me the following exception:

> Trying to invoke abstract method Acme\Bundle\FooBundle\Entity\IFoo::getBody()

Does anyone know if this is possible, or any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you can't annotate an interface, there is a ticket open on github for this issue:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2841

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can use validation for method declarations as they are supposed to be used with properties. You could use an abstract [mapped superclass](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses) for this, though.

Something along the lines of

```php
/** @MappedSuperclass */
abstract class Foo implements FooInterface
{
    /** @Column(type="string")
     *  @Assert\NotBlank
     *  @Assert\MaxLength(3000)
     */
    protected function $body;

    // rest of the class
}
```

You could then extend your other classes from this one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The docs say that you can indeed use getter validations - check it out here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#getters I'm also not sure that using the Abstract class will work out in my specific instance since the class already extends an abstract class which doesn't (and can't) support all the methods of the interface. Also I don't think I can put an abstract in the middle since the way both classes fulfil the interface is quite different - one doesn't even use properties (hence getter validation). That answer would have worked otherwise!